# Optimize mysql query with full text index and other column(s) w/ indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I am running the following query on a table with 100,000+ rows. I am trying to figure out how to use a fulltext index and use an index on other columns that are anded to it. (The create table for phppos_items is at bottom)

```
SELECT name
FROM `phppos_items`
WHERE (MATCH (phppos_items.name, phppos_items.item_number, product_id, description)
       AGAINST ('"Search* "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
          or phppos_items.item_id = 'Search')
  and phppos_items.deleted=0 and system_item = 0;
```

It takes .21 seconds; which is OK; but it isn't fully indexed.

Here is the explain (As you can see it examines 58,188 rows):

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT name FROM `phppos_items` WHERE (MATCH (phppos_items.name, phppo                                                                          LEAN MODE) or phppos_items.item_id = 'Search') and phppos_items.deleted=0 and system_item = 0;
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type | possible_keys                       | key     | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_items | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,deleted,deleted_system_item | deleted | 4       | const | 58188 |     2.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

If I change the query to:

```
SELECT name
FROM `phppos_items`
WHERE (MATCH (phppos_items.name, phppos_items.item_number, product_id, description) AGAINST ('"Search* "' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

It takes 0.0005 seconds and is fully indexed. See explain:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT name FROM `phppos_items` WHERE (MATCH (phppos_items.name, phppos_items.item_number, product_id, description) AGAINST ('"Search* "' IN BOOL
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type     | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                             |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_items | NULL       | fulltext | full_search   | full_search | 0       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
```

Here is create table:

```
mysql> show create table phppos_items;
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| phppos_items | CREATE TABLE `phppos_items` (
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ecommerce_product_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ecommerce_product_quantity` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tax_included` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cost_price` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  `promo_price` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reorder_level` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expire_days` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `allow_alt_description` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_serialized` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `override_default_tax` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_ecommerce` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `is_service` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_ebt_item` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `commission_percent` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `commission_percent_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `commission_fixed` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `change_cost_price` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `disable_loyalty` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ecommerce_last_modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_class_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `replenish_level` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `system_item` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_discount_percent` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_edit_price` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_edit_price` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_1_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_2_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_3_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_4_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_5_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_6_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_7_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_8_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_9_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_10_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `required_age` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verify_age` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `weight` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `width` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ecommerce_shipping_class_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `long_description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `allow_price_override_regardless_of_permissions` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `main_image_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `only_integer` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_series_package` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `series_quantity` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `series_days_to_use_within` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_barcoded` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `default_quantity` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disable_from_price_rules` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `last_edited` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `info_popup` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `item_inactive` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `item_number` (`item_number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `phppos_items_ibfk_1` (`supplier_id`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `phppos_items_ibfk_3` (`category_id`),
  KEY `phppos_items_ibfk_4` (`manufacturer_id`),
  KEY `phppos_items_ibfk_5` (`ecommerce_product_id`),
  KEY `description` (`description`(255)),
  KEY `size` (`size`),
  KEY `reorder_level` (`reorder_level`),
  KEY `cost_price` (`cost_price`),
  KEY `unit_price` (`unit_price`),
  KEY `promo_price` (`promo_price`),
  KEY `last_modified` (`last_modified`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `phppos_items_ibfk_6` (`tax_class_id`),
  KEY `deleted_system_item` (`deleted`,`system_item`),
  KEY `custom_field_1_value` (`custom_field_1_value`),
  KEY `custom_field_2_value` (`custom_field_2_value`),
  KEY `custom_field_3_value` (`custom_field_3_value`),
  KEY `custom_field_4_value` (`custom_field_4_value`),
  KEY `custom_field_5_value` (`custom_field_5_value`),
  KEY `custom_field_6_value` (`custom_field_6_value`),
  KEY `custom_field_7_value` (`custom_field_7_value`),
  KEY `custom_field_8_value` (`custom_field_8_value`),
  KEY `custom_field_9_value` (`custom_field_9_value`),
  KEY `custom_field_10_value` (`custom_field_10_value`),
  KEY `verify_age` (`verify_age`),
  KEY `phppos_items_ibfk_7` (`main_image_id`),
  KEY `item_inactive_index` (`item_inactive`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `full_search` (`name`,`item_number`,`product_id`,`description`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_search` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `item_number_search` (`item_number`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `product_id_search` (`product_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description_search` (`description`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `size_search` (`size`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `custom_field_1_value_search` (`custom_field_1_value`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `custom_field_2_value_search` (`custom_field_2_value`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `custom_field_3_value_search` (`custom_field_3_value`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `custom_field_4_value_search` (`custom_field_4_value`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `custom_field_5_value_search` (`custom_field_5_value`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `custom_field_6_value_search` (`custom_field_6_value`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `custom_field_7_value_search` (`custom_field_7_value`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `custom_field_8_value_search` (`custom_field_8_value`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `custom_field_9_value_search` (`custom_field_9_value`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `custom_field_10_value_search` (`custom_field_10_value`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_suppliers` (`person_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_categories` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_manufacturers` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`tax_class_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_tax_classes` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`main_image_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_item_images` (`image_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20000966 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ten places of precision on monetary amounts seems...generous.

Comment: Don’t think that would affect query as I don’t search those columns

Comment: I'm just pointing that out as it could lead to quirky rounding errors and other weird behaviour that's undesirable. It's always best to clamp that to more reasonable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a serious datatype inconsistency here:

```
`item_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
phppos_items.item_id = 'Search'
```

This is especially messy to try to optimize:

```
WHERE (MATCH (phppos_items.name, phppos_items.item_number, product_id, description)
       AGAINST ('"Search* "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
          or phppos_items.item_id = 'Search')
  and phppos_items.deleted=0
  and system_item = 0;
```

Essentially the only way to perform the query is to check every row of the table.  Furthermore, FT tests like to be "in the driver's seat", but this does not allow such.

Step one is to get rid of the `OR`:

```
( SELECT ...
    WHERE MATCH(..) AGAINST(..)
      AND phppos_items.deleted=0
      AND system_item = 0 )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ...
    WHERE phppos_items.item_id = 'Search'
      AND phppos_items.deleted=0
      AND system_item = 0 )
```

The first `SELECT` will do the FT test (very fast), then filter out any rows based on the 0-tests.

The second `SELECT` will simply use the `PRIMARY KEY(item_id)` (*unless you have a typo!*) and check the numeric item_id against zero and presumably fail to find any rows.

Then the `UNION` will collect the two resultsets, dedup them and deliver the results very fast.

(Turning `OR` into `UNION` is a general optimization technique; it seems especially useful for your query.)

I find it rarely wise to have more than 2 UNIQUE keys on a table.  Are you sure you have 3?